# How to false infiniteLoop in bxslider for carousel?

Tags: bxslider

How can i stop my carousel from infinite loop in bxslider ?

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 170,
  slideMargin: 10,
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd : true
});
```

infiniteLoop is not working here.

thanks.

Comment: @Luther Blisset : Can you explain What you edited ?

Comment: post your full code here ?

Answer (score 4):

look through my code, please..
I created div with ul and li elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.bxSlider ul').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 2,
        slideWidth: 170,
        slideMargin: 10,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd : true
    });

})
```

it is working there